# Creating custom form at registration process for unknown number of nodes

Tags: forms

I have a project where I want to add one OR more "nodes" or content types at registration time. For example, I enter my name and email adress, and then I can add one or more trip (example) I made, and then, later, the content of the site itself will be modified by this information. For example, the main menu could display a tab for each trip (trip1, trip2, etc.).

Any idea where I should start?

Comment: Interesting requirement...hope somebody answers it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

`field_attach_form` to attach the 'trip' content type's fields to user form. (with an alter can become multivalue)

on submit you can use these values to populate the trip entity with `entity_metadata_wrapper` and create a new node

you can build N menu_items than are the trip of the user by a custom menu